# How to play MKV with Bluray Subtitles (PGS) on a PC?

Tags: subtitles, blu-ray, matroska

How to play MKV with Bluray Subtitles (PGS) on a PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

http://www.mediasmartserver.net/2010/06/24/mkvmania-%E2%80%93-displaying-pgs-subtitles-in-mkvs-using-mpc/

Answer (score 4):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is what I use to play almost everything on Windows and Mac. Every version I've used is solid and it's the best software I've found for working with subtitles (especially those in external files). I'm not sure if the most recent version supports SUP files but it certainly is only a matter of time. Even if you find a program in the meantime, you may want to check back periodically for VLC [support](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.php?cat=sub) and see which program you like better.

Also give [BDSup2Sub](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=145277) a try for subtitle file conversion.